# Custom validation using a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, yaml

I have a user sign-up form with a registration code field (:reg_code).  I have a list of valid registration codes (in a yml file, but doesn't have to be if that makes things easier).  I need to check if the user enters in a valid code in the reg code field.  I'm a rails/ruby newbie and have NO CLUE how to load & parse the file to check the reg codes.

My class: (the important parts, anyway)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...more class goodness here...
  before_create :validate_reg_code

  def validate_reg_code
    errors.add(:reg_code, "Sorry, this registration code is invalid.") if reg_code
  end

end
```

I have no clue after the 'if reg code' portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I load the registration codes into the database.  Create a registration code model and then:

```
  def validate_reg_code
    unless RegistrationCode.find_by_code(self.reg_code)
      errors.add(:reg_code, "Sorry, this registration code is invalid.") 
    end
  end
```

If you would like to parse Yaml, you can do so in rails via the YAML::Load command

```
YAML::load(File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/registration_codes.yml"))
```

This will load the yaml file into a hash.  I would need to structure of the yaml file to help you further.